# Unable to mock a class variable in python using pytest

Tags: python, pytest, class-variables, pytest-mock

Below is the test function

```
import pytest
from mock import patch

def test_func1(mocker, fixture_return_value):
    response = A().func1()
    print("response ", response)
    assert response == {'msg': 'Failed, Missing key 1', 'response': False, 'data': {}}
```

Below is the fixture I wrote for the above test

```
@pytest.fixture
def fixture_return_value(mocker, monkeypatch):
    mocker.patch("temp.A._A__return_data", return_value={'key1': {'key2': ""}})
    p = A()
    return p
```

Below is the function that I have to test

```
class A():
    def __init__(self):
        self.__return_data = dict()

    def func1(self):
           try:
                if not self.__return_data['key1']['key2']:
                    return generate_error('Failed, Missing key1')

                for item in self.__return_data['key1']['key2']:
```

I am unable to mock the class variable, `self.__return_data` in the class `A` for the test function `test_func1`. I am getting the following error every time while mocking the class variable :

```
 if not self.__return_data['key1']['key2']:
AttributeError: 'A' object has no attribute '_A__return_data'
```

Comment: Your code and test do not match (`__return_value` vs `__return_data`). Also this is not a class variable, but an instance variable, which you try to mock on the class.

Comment: Thanks, MrBean Bremen for noticing that.